# Invalid Argument: connect() C socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

I'm working on a C program that creates a connection between a client and server. When I run connect on the socket I've already created I keep getting an error that I'm passing an invalid argument.

Any help would be awesome!

```
void client(char* ipAddress, char* serverPort){
    //code for setting up the IP address and socket information from Beej's Guide to Network Programming
    //Need to setup two addrinfo structs. One for the client and one for the server that the connection will be going to
    int status;
    //client addrinfo
    struct addrinfo hints, *res; // will point to the results
    //server addrinfo
    int socketDescriptor;
    int addressLength;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); // make sure the struct is empty
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;     // don't care IPv4 or IPv6
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP stream sockets
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     // fill in my IP for me
    //setup client socket
    if ((status = getaddrinfo(ipAddress, serverPort, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
      printf("%s \n", "This error above");
      fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
      exit(1);
    }

    if((socketDescriptor = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol)) ==-1){
      perror("client: socket");
    }
    addressLength = sizeof hints;
    if(connect(socketDescriptor, res->ai_addr, addressLength)==-1){
      close(socketDescriptor);
      perror("client: connect");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Most likely a mistake for `serverRes`, a `struct addrinfo`?

Comment: You seem to have pasted invalid code, please fix...

Comment: it's a pointer to an addrinfo struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from some inconsistent variable names in your code,
this seems to be wrong:

```
addressLength = sizeof hints;
if(connect(socketDescriptor, res->ai_addr, addressLength)==-1) ...
```

It should be

```
if(connect(socketDescriptor, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen)==-1) ...
```

Comment: @natediggs: `getaddrinfo()` returns a linked list of possible addresses. You probably should iterate through that list and try each one in turn.